# vb.net datatable asenumerble get distinct vlues and count grouped duplicate rows

Tags: vb.net, linq, asenumerable

I have a datatable called dtDealer with 2 columns called Customer, Year. I am trying to make a new datatable called dtdistinct which has an extra column called multi which shows the count for the number of duplicate rows...

dtDealer

Customer | Year

---

AAA         2012

BBB      2011

AAA      2012

BBB      2011

BBB      2011

BBB      2012

dtmulti

Customer | Year | multi

---

AAA      2012      2

BBB      2011      3

BBB      2012      1

tried with asenumerable but not working please help

Comment: "not working" isn't enough detail to diagnose the problem.  Please provide more details on the compiler error or runtime failure.  Also, please provide a MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

AsEnumerable does work. I suspect you had an issue with grouping. I grouped by a Tuple

```
Dim dealers = {(Customer:= "AAA", Year:= 2012),
               (Customer:= "BBB", Year:= 2011),
               (Customer:= "AAA", Year:= 2012),
               (Customer:= "BBB", Year:= 2011),
               (Customer:= "BBB", Year:= 2011),
               (Customer:= "BBB", Year:= 2012)}
Dim dtDealer As New DataTable()
dtDealer.Columns.Add("Customer")
dtDealer.Columns.Add("Year")
For Each dealer In dealers
    Dim row = dtDealer.NewRow()
    row("Customer") = dealer.Customer
    row("Year") = dealer.Year
    dtDealer.Rows.Add(row)
Next

Console.WriteLine($"Customer | Year")
For Each row In dtDealer.AsEnumerable
    Console.WriteLine($"{row("Customer")}{vbTab}{row("Year")}")
Next

Dim dtMulti As New DataTable()
dtMulti.Columns.Add("Customer")
dtMulti.Columns.Add("Year")
dtMulti.Columns.Add("Multi")

dtMulti = dtDealer.AsEnumerable().
          GroupBy(Function(dealer) (dealer("Customer"), dealer("Year"))).
          Select(Function(g)
                     Dim newRow = dtMulti.NewRow()
                     newRow("Customer") = g.First.Item("Customer")
                     newRow("Year") = g.First.Item("Year")
                     newRow("Multi") = g.Count()
                     Return newRow
                 End Function).
          CopyToDataTable()

Console.WriteLine($"Customer | Year | Multi")
For Each row In dtMulti.AsEnumerable
    Console.WriteLine($"{row("Customer")}{vbTab}{row("Year")}{vbTab}{row("Multi")}")
Next
```

> Customer | Year
>
> AAA     2012
>
> BBB     2011
>
> AAA     2012
>
> BBB     2011
>
> BBB     2011
>
> BBB     2012
>
> Customer | Year | Multi
>
> AAA     2012    2
>
> BBB     2011    3
>
> BBB     2012    1